# JOptionPane cancel button doesn't work properly

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, joptionpane

I am working with JOptionPane. it works great when user clicks on the <kbd>ok</kbd> button, but when clicking on the <kbd>cancel</kbd> button and when closing the message as well, it displays the error message.

```
private void findActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

    try {
        String num = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Number to Search:");
        int number = Integer.parseInt(num);
        s.search(number);
   }catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "WRONG INPUT: you must insert integers", "Erorr", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
private void findActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

    try {
        String num = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Number to Search:");
        if(num != null)
        { 
            int number = Integer.parseInt(num);
            s.search(number);
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "WRONG INPUT: you must insert integers", "Erorr", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } 
}
```

`JOptionPane` returns `null` when one closes it or presses cancel. So just check this as the above code shows. And an exception will be thrown when you pass `null` to `Integer.parseInt()`.